What form is a floored or "ceilinged" double when cout represenation has no decimal point and looks like an int?
I wanted to know how to floor a double and I found my solution in this question. I decided to experiment so I wrote the code below.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    double toFloor = 9.4;
    double toCeil = 9.4;
    double toRound = 9.5;

    cout << "toFloor = " << toFloor << std::endl;
    cout << "floored = " << std::floor(toFloor) << std::endl;

    cout << "toCeil = " << toCeil << std::endl;
    cout << "ceiled = " << std::ceil(toCeil) << std::endl;

    cout << "toRound = " << toRound << std::endl;
    cout << "rounded = " << std::round(toRound) << std::endl;

    cout << "floor(9.4)/2 = " << std::round(std::floor(toRound)/2) << std::endl; // added for to see if I would get 5.0

}

However, I was surprised to see that floor(9.4) = 9 and not 9.0 for a double so I did some math on this and divided by 2 only to get 5 and not 5.0. My question is whether this is just the effect of std::cout or if it has something to do with how the double is represented.

read how floating points are formatted to text by streams. This problem is completely unrelated to floor or ceil functions. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed
